# Route detour on Here Maps by dragging the middle of the route

Tags: javascript, here-api

Is possible to implement detour on Here Maps using the javascript API? I skimmed through the documentation but couldn't find a way to allow do rearrange the route and snap it to the streets like in Google Maps.

I have found something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51563188/implementation-of-dragging-route) but it seems limited to the predefined waypoint. And I don't know how the map would know if somehow I added a way to add an object to the map on click

Answer (score 0):

For rerouting/detouring you need to recalculate the route including your place(geocordinate) as one of the waypoints. You can set parameter viewbounds and representation=dragNdrop for getting the reroute only for your viewbounds and not the entire route (optimized way to reroute). Refer developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/route-within-viewport and tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet for detail source code examples. Below is a very simple reroute logic where we have added a draggable marker on a route so that we can reroute via its current location when it is dragged. Replace YOUR-APP-ID and YOUR-APP-CODE with yours accordingly. Hope you find this useful. Happy Coding!

Sample mouse event listener which you can modify to show a marker of your preferred shape instead of the standard one shown in the below example:

```
function setUpClickListener(map) {
  // Attach an event listener to map display
  // obtain the coordinates and display in an alert box.
  map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    var coord = map.screenToGeo(evt.currentPointer.viewportX,
            evt.currentPointer.viewportY);
    alert('Clicked at ' + Math.abs(coord.lat.toFixed(4)) +
        ((coord.lat > 0) ? 'N' : 'S') +
        ' ' + Math.abs(coord.lng.toFixed(4)) +
         ((coord.lng > 0) ? 'E' : 'W'));
  });
}
```

Example code with standard draggable marker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1533195059" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="map" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background:grey" ></div>
  <!--<div id="panel" style="position:absolute; width:49%; left:51%; height:100%; background:inherit" ></div>-->

  <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >


/**
 * Calculates and displays a car route from the Brandenburg Gate in the centre of Berlin
 * to Friedrichstraße Railway Station.
 *
 * A full list of available request parameters can be found in the Routing API documentation.
 * see:  http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html
 *
 * @param   {H.service.Platform} platform    A stub class to access HERE services
 */
function calculateRouteFromAtoB (platform) {
  var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
    routeRequestParams = {
      mode: 'fastest;car',
      representation: 'display',
      routeattributes : 'shape,legs',
      maneuverattributes: 'direction,action',
      waypoint0: '52.5160,13.3779', // Brandenburg Gate
      waypoint1: '52.5206,13.3862'  // Friedrichstraße Railway Station
    };


  router.calculateRoute(
    routeRequestParams,
    onSuccess,
    onError
  );
}

var polyline, marker; 
/**
 * This function will be called once the Routing REST API provides a response
 * @param  {Object} result          A JSONP object representing the calculated route
 *
 * see: http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-type-calculate-route.html
 */
function onSuccess(result) {
  var route = result.response.route[0];
 /*
  * The styling of the route response on the map is entirely under the developer's control.
  * A representitive styling can be found the full JS + HTML code of this example
  * in the functions below:
  */
  addRouteShapeToMap(route);
  if(!marker) addDraggableMarker(route);
}

/**
 * This function will be called if a communication error occurs during the JSON-P request
 * @param  {Object} error  The error message received.
 */
function onError(error) {
  alert('Ooops!');
}




/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

// set up containers for the map  + panel
var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'),
  routeInstructionsContainer = document.getElementById('panel');

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'YOUR-APP-ID',
  app_code: 'YOUR-APP-CODE',
  useHTTPS: true
});
var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
  tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
  ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
});

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Berlin
var map = new H.Map(mapContainer,
  defaultLayers.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:52.5160, lng:13.3779},
  zoom: 13,
  pixelRatio: pixelRatio
});

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

/**
 * Creates a H.map.Polyline from the shape of the route and adds it to the map.
 * @param {Object} route A route as received from the H.service.RoutingService
 */
function addRouteShapeToMap(route){
  var lineString = new H.geo.LineString(),
    routeShape = route.shape;

  routeShape.forEach(function(point) {
    var parts = point.split(',');
    lineString.pushLatLngAlt(parts[0], parts[1]);
  });
  if(polyline) map.removeObject(polyline);
  polyline = new H.map.Polyline(lineString, {
    style: {
      lineWidth: 4,
      strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.7)'
    }
  });
  // Add the polyline to the map
  map.addObject(polyline);
  // And zoom to its bounding rectangle
  map.setViewBounds(polyline.getBounds(), true);
}

function addDraggableMarker(route){
  // setting the draggable marker to a center point when first loaded
  var point = route.shape[Math.floor(route.shape.length/2)].split(',');
  marker = new H.map.Marker(new H.geo.Point(point[0],point[1]));
  // Ensure that the marker can receive drag events
  marker.draggable = true;
  map.addObject(marker);

  // disable the default draggability of the underlying map
  // when starting to drag a marker object:
  map.addEventListener('dragstart', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target;
    if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
      behavior.disable();
    }
  }, false);


  // re-enable the default draggability of the underlying map
  // when dragging has completed
  map.addEventListener('dragend', function(ev) {
    //alert(map.getViewBounds());
    var target = ev.target,
      pointer = ev.currentPointer,
      point = map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX, pointer.viewportY);
    if (target instanceof mapsjs.map.Marker) {
      behavior.enable();
    }
    var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
      routeRequestParams = {
        mode: 'fastest;car',
        representation: 'display',
        routeattributes : 'shape,legs',
        maneuverattributes: 'direction,action',
        waypoint0: '52.5160,13.3779', // Brandenburg Gate
        waypoint1: 'street!passThrough!!'+point.lat+','+point.lng,
        waypoint2: '52.5206,13.3862'  // Friedrichstraße Railway Station
      };


    router.calculateRoute(
      routeRequestParams,
      onSuccess,
      onError
    );

  }, false);
  // Listen to the drag event and move the position of the marker
  // as necessary
   map.addEventListener('drag', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target,
        pointer = ev.currentPointer;
    if (target instanceof mapsjs.map.Marker) {
      target.setPosition(map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX, pointer.viewportY));
    }
  }, false);
}

// Now use the map as required...
calculateRouteFromAtoB (platform);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something like that but without the need for the markers like you guys have on [HERE WeGo](https://wego.here.com) where I hover anywhere with the mouse over the route and can click to drag the route.


EDIT - Also in the demo the marker does no appear to be needed. If I drag the map, the route will be arranged via the position I dragged.

Comment: You need an eventlistener for mouse tap to achieve it. If you see in Here Wego a small bubble occurs on the position of mouse click. You can achieve this by using an icon of your choice instead of the standard one I have used. Edited the answer for a sample mouse event listener code.

Comment: I see where I should go but have other question. If I have a Route with 3 waypoints (A-B-C) and I want to make A-B leg via other road, how does Here WeGo knows it has to drag between A and B?

Comment: @tiagomagalhaes did  you ever manage to implement this?

Comment: @tomvo I don't recall unfortunately. The project I was in was put on hold and I've never returned to it, and even now I do not work for the company I was in at the time of the question